# Get nr of items in an array

Tags: php

I have an array that has this format:

```
array(
  info(
    Date-today => '09/04/2013'
  )
  clients(
    id => 1001,
    name => Fred
  )
  more_info(
    weather-today => "cloudy"
  )
)
```

But sometimes, I receive the data with more clients:

```
array(
  info(
    Date-today => '08/04/2013'
  )
  clients(
    0(
      id => 1001,
      name => Fred
    ),
    1(
      id => 1045,
      name => Fritz
    )
  )
  more_info(
    weather-today => "Sunny"
  )
)
```

I want to count how many cients I got returned, because I need to access the client-data differently if there is only one or more then one.
I tried several "count()" options, such as:

```
count(array['client'])
```

but of course if there is only 1 client, it doesn't return 1, it returns 2 (since there are 2 items of client-data in the array).

Any tips?

Comment: `count(array['clients'])` surely? But even then, it should return the number of clients entries, not the number of subentries in the `clients` array, unless you're calling `count()` with the recursive flag

Comment: @MarkBaker No, because objects here are also arrays, so `count()` would either count the number of "properties" or number of clients.

Comment: use **sizeof(array['subscribers'])** , is subscriber and client same ?
what about **array['subscribers']['clients']** ?

Comment: Do you have any control over the data structure?

Comment: @Jack - so is this an array or an object? and what is the difference between `clients` and `subscribers`?

Comment: I have no control over the data. The data is an object, that is converted into an array. I'm currently using: if(count($array['clients']['0'])>1) but this throws a notice, so I want a cleaner solution.

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm sure it used to be an object, but has now been turned into an array of its properties. And I've assumed that `clients` and `subscribers` is the same thing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to find out whether `$array['clients']` has only numeric indices:

```
$size = count($array['clients'];
if (count(array_filter(array_keys($array['clients']), 'is_int')) == $size) {
    return $size;
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

Alternatively, use the existence of *one* numeric index as the condition:

```
if (isset($array['clients'][0])) {
    return count($array['clients']);
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I fail to see yours. count($array["clients"]) is enough.

Comment: That "dirty trick" is less code and better in my opinion, and there's a parse error in the first bit of code

Comment: @Dale I suppose it would pass in this case :)

Comment: Sorry, just woke up :) Btw, that object looks like a former XML.

Comment: The second bit of code returns 1 if there are no clients, i.e. if the $array['clients'] is defined and empty, right?

Comment: @Martin Yes, but that's unlikely, because it comes from an object originally, and if there were no clients, `$array['clients]` would be undefined and some warnings would show up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array-like structure (as the collection of clients in your example), you should always index the entries, even if there is only one entry.

That way you don't end up with the problem you described.

*EDIT:*
Didn't see your comment.
You can first check if $array['clients'] has any content (via count()).
-> If it hasn't, cnt = 0.
Then check if $array['clients']['0'] is defined.
-> If it isn't defined, cnt = 1.
-> If it is, cnt = count().